# Proof that scaled basis vectors are a basis of vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing

**Problem**

$v_1, ..., v_n$ is a basis of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

Proof that $b_1v_1, ..., b_nv_n$ for $b_1, ..., b_n \in \mathbb{F} \backslash \{0\}$ is a basis of $V$.

**Solution**

The example solution is surprisingly long, proving technicalities that are (I thought) already given because we are scaling basis vectors. Since $b_i \ne 0$, none of the basis vectors $v_i$ can be dropped. Why is it not enough for a proof to just state that

$v_1, ..., v_n$ is a basis for $V \Rightarrow$

$\langle v_1, ..., v_n\rangle = V \land v_1, ..., v_n$ are linearly independent $\Rightarrow$

$\forall i, 1 \le i \le n: b_i v_i \in \langle v_1, ..., v_n \rangle \land b_i v_i \notin \langle v_1, ..., v_{i-1}, v_{i+1}, ..., v_n \rangle \Rightarrow$

$\langle b_1v_1, ..., b_nv_n\rangle = V \land b_1v_1, ..., b_nv_n$ are linearly independent $\Rightarrow$

$b_1v_1, ..., b_nv_n $ is a basis for $V \ \Box$

Comment: All you need is that $b_1v_1,...,b_nv_n$ are linearly independent so then the span of the scaled basis vectors is an $n$-dimensional subspace of $V$ so must be $V$.

Comment: What technicalities is he proving? If the elements of this set were not linearly independent, them you could write one of them (say $b_kv_k$) as a linear combination of the others.  But that would give you an equation that you could multiply by the multiplicative inverse of $b_k$ (since $b_k\neq 0$) to prove that $v_k$ is also a linear combination of the other elements, which is absurd,if the ${v_k}$ form a basis. Finally, if every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of the  ${v_k}$, then it may also be written in terms of the new basis, with new scalars. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your proof doesn't really explain your (correct) claim that $\langle b_1v_1, ..., b_nv_n\rangle = V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the the set of vectors $\{b_1v_1,...,b_nv_n\}$ is not linearly independent. Then there is $k\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $v_kb_k$ is a linear combination of the other elements of the set, which means there are constants $\alpha_i$ not all zero such that $$v_kb_k=\sum_{i\neq k}\alpha_i(b_iv_i),$$ where the sum is over $\{1,...,n\}-\{k\}$. Since $b_k\neq0$, you can multiply this equation by $b_k^{-1}$ and use the fact that $\frac{\alpha_ib_i}{b_k}$ is a scalar in $F$ to deduce $v_k$ is can be written as linear combination of the other $v_i$. This would contradict the fact that  $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, so it must be false. Thus these vectors are linearly independent. Finally, any element $u$ of $V$ can be written in the form  $$u=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i(b_iv_i),$$ where $c_i=a_i/b_i$. Since the $b_i$ are assumes to be zero, $c_i$ always exists. So this set does indeed span $V$ and must be a basis.
As others pointed out in the comments, you only proved the first part (the linear independence.)